# mysql query comparing 2 date ranges

Tags: php, mysql, date

here's my data structure:

```
seasons
id  from         to           name      
----------------------------------------
1   2015-11-01   2015-12-15   season1   
2   2015-12-16   2015-12-30   season2   
3   2015-12-31   2016-01-20   season3   

rooms_free
id  from         to           room_id
----------------------------------------
1   2015-11-26   2015-11-30   1   
2   2015-12-19   2015-12-28   2
3   2015-12-22   2015-12-29   3
```

i need an sql query which will join both tables by date range returning the following result:

```
id_room  room_from    room_to      season_id    season_name
-------------------------------------------------------------
1        2015-11-26   2015-11-30   1            season1   
2        2015-12-19   2015-12-28   2            season2
3        2015-12-22   2015-12-29   2            season2
```

could this be done using normal statements or would i need a mysql function?
any ideas?

ps: the really tricky part is when there's several seasons per room ..

Comment: But what if the room overlaps the seasons!?!

Comment: can you expand the sample for the several seasons per room? As currently every room has only one season. And you desire output

Answer (score 4):

This is the best explanation about overlaping data ranges

[Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f1d86/5)

```
SELECT rf.room_id as id_room ,
       rf.from as room_from,
       rf.to as room_to,
       s.id as season_id,
       s.name as season_name
FROM rooms_free rf
JOIN seasons s
  ON (rf.From <= s.to)  and  (rf.to >= s.from)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| room_id |                       from |                         to | id |    name |
|---------|----------------------------|----------------------------|----|---------|
|       1 | November, 26 2015 00:00:00 | November, 30 2015 00:00:00 |  1 | season1 |
|       2 | December, 19 2015 00:00:00 | December, 28 2015 00:00:00 |  2 | season2 |
|       3 | December, 22 2015 00:00:00 | December, 29 2015 00:00:00 |  2 | season2 |
```

Comment: @BarışKURT Is great to make better question and to prove your answer works :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, you are joining where a room is free before and after a season. But what if a room is free during a season, but not until its end or not from its start?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, i will use it too anymore :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, come on. I do not need to read a link to be able to determine that  ON (rf.From <= s.to)  and  (rf.to >= s.from) will not join records where rf.from <= s.to <= s.from which is a clear case when the intersection is not an empty set. Since you did not correct your error, I have to down-vote your answer.

Comment: Oh, wait. You are right. I misread your sql. Let me undo the down-vote, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @LajosArpad That is why I point you to the link, there `Charles Bretana` make a very good explanation on why that work.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT rooms_free.id as id_room, rooms_free.from as room_from , rooms_free.to as room_to, seasons.id as season_id,       seasons.name as season_name FROM `rooms_free` join seasons on rooms_free.`from`>=seasons.from and rooms_free.`to`<=seasons.to

Answer (score 0):

```
select rooms_free.id as id_room, rooms_free.from as room_from, rooms_free.to as room_to, seasons.id as season_id,  seasons.name as season_name
from rooms_free
join seasons
on ((rooms.from <= seasons.from) and (seasons.from <= rooms.to)) or ((seasons.from <= rooms.from) and (rooms.from <= seasons.to))
```

The statement above checks for strict overlapping. If there are several seasons per room, then you can use `group by`, `having` and `group_concat`.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily verbose

Comment: What do you consider to be unnecessary and why?

Comment: Refer to the other answers

Answer (score -1):

```
Select rooms_free.id, rooms_free.from, rooms_free.to, seasons.id,       seasons.name 
from rooms_free , seasons 
where (rooms_free.from >= season.from and rooms_free.to <= seasons.to)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.